# Why can't diy.se connect to Europe / VPN?

Tags: support, bug

I use a VPN so I have a European IP address, Sweden, Poland, Germany etc. depending on which port I land on.  Connectivity to diy.stackexchange.com is intermittent - every week or so, it will go down for hours at a time.  I am unable to even begin to load any page (the Safari progress bar stops at the first place it stops, and never advances.

Works fine from a North American IP address, and diy.meta works too.  Every other random stack that I try also seems to work fine.  *Just* DIY.

For instance I provided an answer to [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/121775/water-heater-too-hot-possibly-caused-by-low-water-flow?noredirect=1#comment190244_121775) at 1pm, and it's now 6pm and the thing is still beachballing: [image]

I can't even retry, not that it would work; diy.se doesn't load in other windows either.

Any idea what makes diy.se special(ly terrible)?